# How to Decrypt Password in c# using Salt and Hash.?

Tags: c#, cryptography, passwords

How to Decrypt Password in c# using Salt and Hash.? Salt and Hash already stored in SQL Server.

[image: Hash & Salt]

Here is attached screenshot of Database with hash salt and Hash.

Comment: It's going to be fairly difficult. Hashing algorithms are one-way... See here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee783861(v=cs.20).aspx

Comment: It depends how you encrypted it. Usually encryption and decryption come together.

Comment: why is this tagged as base64? Base64 is encoding, not encryption.

Comment: Post the code used to encrypt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that this table is all there is, that there is no 'password' column or table. In which case:

**There are no passwords here to decrypt, because this table does not contain passwords.**

Here's what's going on: the user creates a password. It's hashed (using the salt) and stored as `123ABC`. When they log on, they enter the password, which is then hashed (using the salt) and *compared* to the saved hash. If it comes out as `123ABC`, fine.

The good part is, you never save the passwords, so they can't be stolen. Ever.

The bad part is that *other* strings will *also* hash to `123ABC`, so someone with a table of all possible hashes (called a 'rainbow table') can get in using some other, known match. That's where the salt comes it, it makes it much harder to figure out possible matches.

Comment: No one, not even the NSA, has a "table of all possible hashes". That table would have more rows than atoms in the known universe.

Comment: @Sam Real-world hashes (which is what the OP is concerned with) are of a limited number of common sizes. A standard 128-bit hash has only 2^128 possible values, and you only need one matching decrypt for each. Look up "rainbow tables" and you'll see why this matters.

Comment: True, if you limit the set of passwords then it's possible to have those tables, but I was referring to your mention of *all possible* hashes. As you said, there are "only 2^128 possible values" for 128-bit hashes, and I find the use of the word "only" a bit puzzling, as if that number was nothing to worry about. Do you really think you could have a table with all those possible values?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you encrypt it, you probably can't decrypt it as Hash algorithms are generally one-way.

The only viable solution you have would be to bruteforce the hash and salt which by looking at it would take forever.

If you know how the data is encrypted in relation to the salt then this is relatively simple, and can be done either manually or automatically.

More about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee783861(v=cs.20).aspx